# Export to txt file error occurred

Tags: php, file

I have exported data to a text file using PHP/MYSQL. I wrote into `file.txt` created using the instruction below:

```
fwrite($fp ,'' . $value. '' . "\t");
```

Every thing goes right, but some problem appears when a field in the DB contains a `','` character, like this:

```
Section= Society, Education & Youth
```

So in the text file created the section value appears in two columns separated and that's wrong, because the value of section is a one and should be inserted in one cell (I see the problem in excel file)

So the problem is, how can I tell the output to ignore the `','` in some values so that it wouldn't be taken as two columns?

Comment: Use fputcsv() to solve a lot of these issues

Comment: fputcsv() can be used for a text file????

Comment: a CSV file (or a Tab-Separated Value file as you're trying to generate by hand) __is__ a text file... it's simply a text file with a basic structure

Answer (score 0):

A comma-separated value (CSV) file can use a delimiter character, usually quotes, to denote text for just that case. If your data does not have quotes within the text than you can give that a try. You can tell Excel what the delimiter is. You can also use a different characters (tab, comma, etc.) to delimit the fields just as long as Excel knows how you're delimiting the data.

```
// try with quotes
fwrite($fp, "\"$value\"\t");
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape any " that might exist in $value as ""

Comment: kindly; i use fwrite($fp, "\"$value\"\t");
 when $value='some thing,...,' , than the same problem appears...

Comment: Try using Import from excel or give the filename a `.txt` extension to start the Import Wizard so that you can tell Excel how your data is delimited. If the file has a `.csv` extension *I think* excel makes assumptions about how it's delimited.

Comment: ok , some text into cells contents characters like "/", "''",'""',..., how proceed to escape character for best view of file exported???